# How do I get a List by name

Tags: c#, forms, list, rows, picturebox

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is add the the control to the corresponding List "row"+row, (whatever the row number is current in the for loop), however, I can't seem to find a way to get a list reference by string. I was wondering if there is a way to do this.

```
    List<PictureBox> row1 = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> row2 = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> row3 = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> row4 = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> row5 = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> row6 = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> row7 = new List<PictureBox>();
private void fillLists()
    {
        for (int col = 1; col < 7; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < 6; row++)
            {
                string name = "row_"+row+"_col_"+col;

                PictureBox picture = (PictureBox)this.Controls[name];

                // "row"+row.Add(picture);

            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**
- Added this, going to see if it works. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
private void fillLists()
    {
        for (int col = 1; col < 7; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < 6; row++)
            {
                string name = "row_" + row + "_col_" + col;
                if (!rows.ContainsKey(row))
                {
                    rows.Add(row, new List<PictureBox>());
                }

                rows[row].Add((PictureBox)this.Controls[name]);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Dictionary to combine all your collections:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<PictureBox>> 
for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    dict.Add("row"+i, new List<PictureBox>);
}
```

then access it with:

```
dict["row1"].Add(....);
```

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. thanks! But it still doesn't answer my question. I'm going to change my programming, but I'm still curious as to how things are accessed dynamically through a string. =) Solely, because I love programming.

Comment: You can't form variable names with other variables, you have to add them to a reference system. This is probably the best/easiest option. The only other way to do it involves reflection.

Comment: `how things are accessed dynamically through a string` are you asking how dictionaries work, or how you could make your original code work?  For the latter, you'd have to use reflection, which would be 1000% terrible in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to know how to do it, here is how it can be done using reflection:

```
class Program
{
    List<object> myList1 = new List<object>();
    List<object> myList2 = new List<object>();
    List<object> myList3 = new List<object>();
    List<object> myList4 = new List<object>();
    List<object> myList5 = new List<object>();
    List<object> myList6 = new List<object>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Run();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            FieldInfo field = this.GetType().GetField("myList" + i, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (field != null)
            {
                List<object> value = field.GetValue(this) as List<object>;

                if (value != null)
                {
                     //You can use it here
                }
                else
                {
                     //Wasn't found
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note though that this is dramatically slower than just adding your Lists to a dictionary and using a named index. It does demonstrate how to get the field though, this is a Console program and can be copy/pasted into any new console project.

Comment: Thank you so much, could I ask, why is it slower? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Reflection is slow, it has to reflect on its own type structure to get data out. Hash table look ups (like dictionaries) are much faster.

Comment: That actually makes sense, thank you so much for taking the time to explain everything. Have a great day!